# Oracle time (eg. 21:03:18) in varchar2 to number

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, dst

I have a problem with a time column in my database. I created procedures to adjust summer and winter time and I am use it like below but it is very slow solution, I have to wait more then one minute for a report with that case, without it execution time is ~4 seconds

```sql
CASE WHEN i.created_on BETWEEN get_first_day_of_spring(EXTRACT(year FROM i.created_on)) AND get_first_day_of_fall(EXTRACT(year FROM i.created_on)) 
    THEN to_char(substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),1,2)+2||':'||substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),3,2)||':'|| substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),5,2))
    ELSE to_char(substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),1,2)+1||':'||substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),3,2)||':'|| substr(REPLACE(i.time_,':',''),5,2))
```

Is it any way to change database type from vachar2 to number?

[image]

Comment: Why are you holding time as a separate column - if it relates to `created_on`? And why are you doing your own DST handling when Oracle has that built-in? Anyway... you can't store 09:37:03 as a number unless you convert it to a number of seconds. You can convert that string to an interval as part of your query though. This seems like a flawed approach though.

Comment: Your method is flawed as DST typically changes between `02:00` and `03:00` and you are assuming that it changes at `00:00`.

Comment: @AlexPoole I retrieving the data from SAP where `time` is in another column than `created_at` @MT0 good point, fortunately system works only between 6 AM till 10 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string functions, convert your strings to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and then use `AT TIME ZONE <your timezone>` to convert it to your expected output.

For example, if your data is stored in the table in the `UTC` time zone and you want it in your local time zone in, for example, `Europe/Berlin` then:

```sql
SELECT created_on,
       time_,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           created_on || time_ || ' UTC',
           'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS TZD'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin',
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       ) AS dst_date_germany,
       TO_CHAR(
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
           created_on || time_ || ' UTC',
           'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS TZD'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin',
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS dst_time_germany
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( created_on, time_ ) AS
SELECT '2021-01-01', '00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-03-27', '23:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-03-28', '00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-03-28', '02:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31', '00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2021-10-31', '02:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CREATED_ON | TIME_    | DST_DATE_GERMANY | DST_TIME_GERMANY
> :--------- | :------- | :--------------- | :---------------
> 2021-01-01 | 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01       | 01:00:00        
> 2021-03-27 | 23:00:00 | 2021-03-28       | 00:00:00        
> 2021-03-28 | 00:00:00 | 2021-03-28       | 01:00:00        
> 2021-03-28 | 02:00:00 | 2021-03-28       | 04:00:00        
> 2021-10-31 | 00:00:00 | 2021-10-31       | 02:00:00        
> 2021-10-31 | 02:00:00 | 2021-10-31       | 03:00:00
> ```

Even better, merge your `created_on` and `time_` string columns into a single `created_on` column with the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type and then you can just convert between time zones.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ( created_on2 DATE );
UPDATE table_name
SET created_on2 = TO_DATE( created_on || time_, 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS' );
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN created_on;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN time_;
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN created_on2 TO created_on;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT created_on,
       FROM_TZ( CAST( created_on AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' )
         AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'
         AS dst_germany
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CREATED_ON          | DST_GERMANY                    
> :------------------ | :------------------------------
> 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00.000000 CET 
> 2021-03-27 23:00:00 | 2021-03-28 00:00:00.000000 CET 
> 2021-03-28 00:00:00 | 2021-03-28 01:00:00.000000 CET 
> 2021-03-28 02:00:00 | 2021-03-28 04:00:00.000000 CEST
> 2021-10-31 00:00:00 | 2021-10-31 02:00:00.000000 CEST
> 2021-10-31 02:00:00 | 2021-10-31 03:00:00.000000 CET
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f849e311236dc766d9cca3542a118c0e)*